# sqlite database updating Gridview when searching with a searchview

Tags: java, android

i was able to create a database and fill it with some foods !! and display them in a gridview  take a look [screenshot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQLGW.png)

i want to know how i can make the search view work so that when i search for a food the gridview gets updated too !!!

the second problem is : i implemented OnItemClickListener for each subitem in the gridview

public class FoodList extends AppCompatActivity {

```
GridView gridView;
static ArrayList<Food> list;
FoodListAdapter adapter = null;
SearchView sv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.food_list_activity);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new FoodListAdapter(this, R.layout.food_items, list);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

   // get all data from sqlite
   Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM FOOD ");
    list.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String price = cursor.getString(2);
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);

        list.add(new Food(name, price, image, id));
    }
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Food food = list.get(position);
            Intent i = new Intent(FoodList.this,Details.class);
            i.putExtra("position", position);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
```

}

but this wont work when i add the searchview !! because the positions of the subitems will change and it wont return the right position when

Food food = list.get(position);

here is the activity that i am starting when subitems are clicked

```
public class Details extends AppCompatActivity {
 int position;
Button b;
EditText edi;
ImageView im;
TextView text;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.hotelbu);
    edi=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.hoteled);
    im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hotelim);
    text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hoteltx);

    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position", 0);
    }

    switch(position){

        case 9999:



            break;
        default:

            text.setText(FoodList.list.get(position).getName());
            edi.setText(FoodList.list.get(position).getPrice());
            break;
    }
}
}
```

i hope you guys understand what i am looking for , sorry for my bad english , any help is appreciated Thank you

Comment: Obviously you should use primary key for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have to use AutoCompleteTextView instead of simple EditText. AutoCompleteTextView is an editable text view that shows a list of suggestions in a drop down list automatically when user is typing, from which the user can choose an item to replace the content of the edit box with.

```
auto_complete_textview = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_textview);

             auto_complete_textview.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });
```

Now create an adapter class that extends BaseAdapter and implements Filterable interface, override all methods of BaseAdapter and getFilter() method of Filterable interface and do all stuff what you want.

You can see the example of AutoCompleteTextView on this link

[http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example]

This is the xml code to create AutoCompleteTextView

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/auto_complete_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search"/>
```

Comment: thank you so much , with some changes it works perfectly